# std::filesystem::directory_iterator fails with cyrillic letters

Tags: c++, codepages, charset

I am trying to create a file retriever. It works fine so far, except for the fact that it quits if e.g. Cyrillic characters appear in the file or directory name. In the C++ description of `directory_iterator`, I didn't find any hints about this. I am puzzled by this, especially since the Windows OS has no difficulties with Cyrillic characters, and I did not find any hints in the corresponding cppreference docs. What's the issue? Which keywords do I have to deal with?

```
/** C++17 boost-less fileSubDirIteration, core from
https://www.cppstories.com/2019/04/dir-iterate/  */

/** mandatory */
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
std::string dirList[100];
std::ofstream fp;
void DisplayPath(const fs::path&, int); 
  
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) { printf("fSDI.exe <startPath> <outFile>\n"); exit(0); }
    const fs::path toRetrieve(argv[1]);
    std::string out(argv[2]);
    fp.open(out, std::ios::out);
    fp << "retrieve: " << toRetrieve << std::endl;
    dirList[0] = fs::absolute(toRetrieve).string();
    DisplayPath(toRetrieve,0);
    fp.close();
}

void DisplayPath(const fs::path& pathToScan,int lv = 0)
{
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(pathToScan))
    {
        const auto file = entry.path().filename().string();
        if (entry.is_directory())
        {
            fp << "[" <<  entry.path().filename().string() << "]" << std::endl;
            dirList[lv+1] = entry.path().filename().string();
            DisplayPath(entry, lv + 1);
        }
        else if (entry.is_regular_file())
        {
            std::string fullPath;
            fullPath += dirList[0];
            if (!(dirList[0].compare(2, 1, "\\", 0, 1) == 0 && dirList[0].size() == 3))
                fullPath += "\\";
            for(int i=1;i<=lv;i++) fullPath += (dirList[i] + "\\" );
            fp << " " << fullPath << file << std::endl;
        }
        else;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "_it quits_" mean? Is there a segmentation fault or similar? If so where and what kind exactly? What does the debugger say about the contents of relevant variables at the point of the crash? Etc.

Comment: Use `std::wstring` for handling non-ASCII strings, and also because Windows Unicode is based on UTF-16 anyway. `std::string` doesn't handle Cyrillic unless it is encoded in UTF-8 (eg, via `fs::path::u8string()` instead of `fs::path::string()`). Also, you might consider changing your `dirList[]` array to hold `fs::path` instead of `std::string` (and also change it to `std::vector` to remove the arbitrary 100 element limit). Let `fs::path` handle concatenating path segments for you, don't do it manually. The `<filesystem>` library was invented to offer better path management.

Comment: Remy - ok, the hint to trust the methods of fs::path when composing the path was crucial. As a newby I didn't expect them to be this powerful. It made the code amazingly compact and my fiddling with the datatypes obsolete. u8string() but string() solved the charctre problem.